Avoid crosss-toggle between legend items when using errorbar and pick_event
Using Matplotlib version 3.8.4, suspecting this might be a bug. Newbie to Python.
When plotting errorbar in a figure, the sample code below experiences an unusually large hitbox for the pick_event toggle resulting in unwanted multi-selection of items in the legend. Couldn't figure out from the documentation why changing pickradius doesn't seem to help, appears to be a bug:
I also commented this problem on github under a similar issue previously raised by someone else: (https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/1962)
I tried several work-around attempts, none which worked. Can't find a similar attempt either.
Also, one legend item toggle doesn't work and I'm not sure why? Thanks in advance <3
from   matplotlib         import pyplot as plt, patches
from matplotlib.lines     import Line2D      # Can be used to check event.artist type. (doesn't resolve problem)
from matplotlib.patches   import Rectangle   # Can be used to check event.artist type. (doesn't resolve problem)
from matplotlib.offsetbox import VPacker
import numpy as np
%matplotlib qt5 

'''
def print_version(): # So matplotlib is only imported when checking version, not able to affect code.
    import matplotlib
    print('matplotlib: {}'.format(matplotlib.__version__))

print_version() # I'm using version 3.8.4
'''

x  = np.arange(0.1,4,0.5)
y0 = np.exp(-x)*1.2-0.25
y1 = np.exp(-x)
y2 = np.exp(-x)*1.2+0.25

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
ax.grid(True)

(m, )     = ax.plot(x  , y1  , color = "red" , label = "line_m")
(n, )     = ax.plot(x*2, y1*2, color = "red" , label = "line_n")
shadow_1  = ax.fill_between(x, y0, y2, label = 'shadow_1')
(a, b, c) = ax.errorbar(x  , y2  , yerr=0.1, color="blue" , marker='*', capsize=4, label="errorbar a")
(d, e, f) = ax.errorbar(x+2, y2+2, xerr=0.1, color="green", marker='.', capsize=4, label="errorbar d") 
(g, h, i) = ax.errorbar(x-2, y2-2, yerr=0.1, xerr=0.1, color='black', marker='o', capsize=4, label='errorbar g')

leg = ax.legend()
leg.set_draggable(True)

lines           = [m, n]
fill_plots      = [shadow_1]

bars_line       = [a, d, g]          # line of errorbar
bars_lower      = [b[0], e[0], h[0]] # lower error bar
bars_upper      = [b[1], e[1], h[1]] # upper error bar
bars_vertical   = [c, f, i]          # vertical line through datapoint

pickradius      = 5

map_legend_to_ax = {}                   
for legend_line, ax_line in zip(leg.get_lines(), lines):
    legend_line.set_picker(pickradius) 
    map_legend_to_ax[legend_line] = ax_line

leg_to_fill = {}
for leg_obj, fill_plot in zip(leg.findobj(patches.Rectangle), fill_plots):
    leg_obj.set_picker(pickradius)
    leg_to_fill[leg_obj] = fill_plot

line_to_error_bars = {}
for line_obj, errorbar_line in zip(leg.get_children(), bars_line): # leg.findobj(VPacker) also works sometimes.
    line_obj.set_picker(pickradius)
    line_obj.pickradius = 1
    line_to_error_bars[line_obj] = errorbar_line

upper_error = {}
for obj, upper in zip(leg.get_children(), bars_upper):
    obj.set_picker(pickradius)
    obj.pickradius = 1
    upper_error[obj] = upper

lower_error = {}
for obj, lower in zip(leg.get_children(), bars_lower): 
    obj.set_picker(1)
    obj.pickradius = 1
    lower_error[obj] = lower

vertical_error_line = {}
for obj, vertical in zip(leg.get_children(), bars_vertical): 
    obj.set_picker(True)
    obj.pickradius = 1 
    vertical_error_line[obj] = vertical

def toggle_(event, fig, map_legend_to_ax, leg_to_fill, line_to_error_bars, lower_error, upper_error, vertical_error_line):
    '''Using pick_event (select with mouse click), find the original line/shadow corresponding to the legend 
       proxy line/shadow, and toggle its visibility.'''
    legend_plot_object = event.artist
    shadow_alpha_off   = 0.2

    # Can also use isinstance(artist, Line2D) etc. here. Tried to see if we can avoid toggle error this way... nope :(
    condition_errorbar = (legend_plot_object in line_to_error_bars) and (legend_plot_object in lower_error) and (legend_plot_object in upper_error) and (legend_plot_object in vertical_error_line)
    condition_shadow   = (legend_plot_object in leg_to_fill)
    condition_line     = (legend_plot_object in map_legend_to_ax)

    if condition_line and not condition_errorbar:
        legend_line = legend_plot_object
        ax_line     = map_legend_to_ax[legend_line]
        visible     = not ax_line.get_visible()
        ax_line.set_visible(visible)
        legend_line.set_alpha(1.0 if visible else shadow_alpha_off)
        fig.canvas.draw()
        return True

    if condition_shadow and not condition_errorbar:
        leg_obj   = legend_plot_object
        fill_plot = leg_to_fill[leg_obj]
        visible   = not fill_plot.get_visible()
        fill_plot.set_visible(visible)
        leg_obj.set_alpha(1.0 if visible else shadow_alpha_off)
        fig.canvas.draw()
        return True
    
    elif condition_errorbar: 
        leg_obj        = legend_plot_object
        line_and_error = line_to_error_bars[leg_obj]
        lower_bar      = lower_error[leg_obj]
        upper_bar      = upper_error[leg_obj]
        vertical_bar   = vertical_error_line[leg_obj]
        visible_line     = not line_and_error.get_visible()
        visible_lower    = not lower_bar.get_visible()
        visible_upper    = not upper_bar.get_visible()
        for i in vertical_bar:
            visible_i = not i.get_visible()
            i.set_visible(visible_i)

        line_and_error.set_visible(visible_line)
        lower_bar.set_visible(visible_lower)
        upper_bar.set_visible(visible_upper)

        leg_obj.set_alpha(1.0 if (visible_line and visible_lower) else shadow_alpha_off)
        fig.canvas.draw()
        return True

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', lambda event: toggle_(event, 
                                                           fig, 
                                                           map_legend_to_ax, 
                                                           leg_to_fill, 
                                                           line_to_error_bars, 
                                                           lower_error, 
                                                           upper_error, 
                                                           vertical_error_line)
                                                           ) 

plt.show()


Tried changing pickradius of errorbar, VPacker doesn't have a set_pickerradius so assigned pickradius directly. Doesn't affect the toggling.
Tried adding a custom legend icon and label, didn't resolve the problem.
Tried to use mousehover so check which item the mouse is over, always returns false hence didn't work.
Tried tracking the number of event triggers and using the last entry, didn't work as I can't predict when the final trigger is.
Tried placing each errorbar in its own legend, works but not pragmatic.
Tried increasing spacing between labels and legend icons, didn't work.
Can't remember what else I tried over the last few weeks!

